# How check that there is post thumbnail feature image or not on wordpress?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails, images

On my wordpress site ,

I have some post that all of them have post thumbnail, but their post thumbnail removed from host and now when i want to load them on site , there is no image for loading to user ,
I want to know how can i set that if feature image is removed, show default image?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is what exactly was removed. If only thumbnails, then you can always regenerate them and everything should work OK.

If all files are missing, then you can check if attached file is missing using this code:

```
if ( file_exists( get_attached_file ( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) ) ) {
    // file exists
} else {
    // file doesn’t exist
}
```

You can also use [`wp_attachment_is_image`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_attachment_is_image) function for that:

```
if ( wp_attachment_is_image ( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ) ) {
    // file exists
} else {
    // file doesn’t exist
}
```